# Node js and mongodb failed to connect to server [70.32.xx.xx:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm new learning for nodejs and i had deployed my api application using express on a2Hosting for node js app, and i'm using mongoose db, after all setup configration and start monodb.service on my VPS host, i cannot connect to the mongoose.connect(URI); and i got this error.

> ```
> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [serverIPXX.XX.XX:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 70.32.24.12:27017
>     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
>   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
> }]
>     at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
>     at Pool.emit (events.js:209:13)
>     at /home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:561:14
>     at /home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:994:11
>     at /home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7
>     at callback (/home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)
>     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/perjoaho/nodevenv/PrjoApp/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)
>     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:297:20)
>     at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
>     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
>     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11) {
>   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
>   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
> }
> ```

////////////

connection code

> ```
> mongoose.connect("mongodb://XX.XX.XX:27017/perjodb", {useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true});
> var db = mongoose.connection;
> db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
> db.once('open', function() {
>   // we're connected!
>  console.log("DB Connected");
>
> });
> ```

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means the operating system at the destination actively refused the connection because nothing is listening on that port.

Comment: @Joe
I tried to use the connection String on my app on the local (laptob) and the db connected perfectly, is it a sign for somthing ?